# Tensorflow Serving - No versions of servable <model> found under base path

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, textsum

I'm currently trying to use tensorflow serving to serve a trained "**textsum**" model. I am using **TF 0.11**, which after some reading, it seems automatically calls export_meta_graph which creates the exported files **ckpt** and **ckpt.meta** files.

Under the textsum/log_root directory, I have multiple files. One being **model.ckpt-230381** and the other **model.ckpt-230381.meta**.

So it is my understanding that this is the location I should be able to point when trying to setup the model for serving. I have issued the below commands:

```
bazel build //tensorflow_serving/model_servers:tensorflow_model_server

bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/model_servers/tensorflow_model_server --port=9000 --model_name=model  --model_base_path=tf_models/textsum/log_root/
```

Upon running the above command I get the below message:

> W
>   tensorflow_serving/sources/storage_path/file_system_storage_path_source.cc:204]
>   No versions of servable model found under base path
>   tf_models/textsum/log_root/

Upon running inspect_checkpoint on the checkpoint file I see this:

```
> I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened
> CUDA library libcublas.so locally I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA
> library libcudnn.so locally I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA
> library libcufft.so locally I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA
> library libcuda.so.1 locally I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA
> library libcurand.so locally seq2seq/output_projection/w (DT_FLOAT)
> [256,335906] seq2seq/output_projection/v (DT_FLOAT) [335906]
> seq2seq/encoder3/BiRNN/FW/LSTMCell/B (DT_FLOAT) [1024]
> seq2seq/encoder3/BiRNN/BW/LSTMCell/W_0 (DT_FLOAT) [768,1024]
> seq2seq/encoder3/BiRNN/BW/LSTMCell/B (DT_FLOAT) [1024]
> seq2seq/encoder2/BiRNN/FW/LSTMCell/B (DT_FLOAT) [1024]
> seq2seq/decoder/attention_decoder/Linear/Bias (DT_FLOAT) [128]
> seq2seq/decoder/attention_decoder/AttnW_0 (DT_FLOAT) [1,1,512,512]
> seq2seq/decoder/attention_decoder/AttnV_0 (DT_FLOAT) [512]
> seq2seq/encoder0/BiRNN/FW/LSTMCell/W_0 (DT_FLOAT) [384,1024]
> seq2seq/decoder/attention_decoder/LSTMCell/W_0 (DT_FLOAT) [384,1024]
> seq2seq/encoder1/BiRNN/BW/LSTMCell/W_0 (DT_FLOAT) [768,1024]
> global_step (DT_INT32) [] seq2seq/encoder1/BiRNN/BW/LSTMCell/B
> (DT_FLOAT) [1024]
> seq2seq/decoder/attention_decoder/AttnOutputProjection/Linear/Bias
> (DT_FLOAT) [256]
> seq2seq/decoder/attention_decoder/Attention_0/Linear/Matrix (DT_FLOAT)
> [512,512] seq2seq/decoder/attention_decoder/Attention_0/Linear/Bias
> (DT_FLOAT) [512] seq2seq/encoder2/BiRNN/BW/LSTMCell/B (DT_FLOAT)
> [1024] seq2seq/decoder/attention_decoder/Linear/Matrix (DT_FLOAT)
> [640,128]
> seq2seq/decoder/attention_decoder/AttnOutputProjection/Linear/Matrix
> (DT_FLOAT) [768,256] seq2seq/embedding/embedding (DT_FLOAT)
> [335906,128] seq2seq/encoder0/BiRNN/BW/LSTMCell/B (DT_FLOAT) [1024]
> seq2seq/encoder3/BiRNN/FW/LSTMCell/W_0 (DT_FLOAT) [768,1024]
> seq2seq/encoder0/BiRNN/BW/LSTMCell/W_0 (DT_FLOAT) [384,1024]
> seq2seq/encoder0/BiRNN/FW/LSTMCell/B (DT_FLOAT) [1024]
> seq2seq/decoder/attention_decoder/LSTMCell/B (DT_FLOAT) [1024]
> seq2seq/encoder1/BiRNN/FW/LSTMCell/B (DT_FLOAT) [1024]
> seq2seq/encoder2/BiRNN/FW/LSTMCell/W_0 (DT_FLOAT) [768,1024]
> seq2seq/encoder1/BiRNN/FW/LSTMCell/W_0 (DT_FLOAT) [768,1024]
> seq2seq/encoder2/BiRNN/BW/LSTMCell/W_0 (DT_FLOAT) [768,1024]
```

Did I misunderstand what needs to occur for exporting? Any ideas on why the model is not getting found?

Comment: Just a wild guess, but perhaps try using an absolute path instead of relative?

Comment: Thanks Robert, but that happens to be a different error when that is the case. This too was the first thing I thought it might be.  When it can't find the path, the error is: FileSystemStoragePathSource encountered a file-system access error: Could not find base path /tf_models/textsum for servable model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I am still struggling with getting the textsum model exported for tensorflow serving, it seems that my issue here was that I was assuming that when the model was saving the files mentioned above that those were the same files created when exporting a model. Based on an answer I received on git, this seems to not be the case and I do in fact have to run the export on the model itself. At that point, TF serving should be able to see the model.

Comment: What you mean is TF serving takes in `frozen_inference_graph.pb` instead of `saved_model.pb` itself? Can you please eleborate more on this?